# How to calculate 404 error of a site in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, curl, wget

I want wget to crawl all links in a site (the site is small) and count the number of 404 Not Found errors in the links.
The following script will check the status of a link

```
wget --server-response $link 2>&1 | awk '/^  HTTP/{print $2}'
```

also I can get the links of a domain with the following script

```
wget --spider --recursive --no-verbose --output-file=wgetlog.txt $domain
```

How can I combine these two scripts to calculate dead links for a bunch of sites?

Comment: good for you :) did you try anything yet?

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Requests for 
tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Don't write this in `bash`; use a language that has a library for making HTTP requests instead of running `curl` or `wget` repeatedly.